# how do we display all posts from a particular category in homepage?

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to show all the posts of a particular category on my home page. There are over 70 posts in that category. I would like have a pagination so that only 10 posts are displayed and have pagination set so users can move to next page by clicking the page nos.
Can this be possible?
Here is the current code that i have

```
   global $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 0, 'ORDER BY'=>'date', 'order'=>'desc','category' => 1 );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); 
          //  while(have_posts()):the_post();
            $attrs = array(
        'src'   => $src,
        'class' => "",
        'alt'   => get_the_title(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
    );
```

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) on the Codex for `get_posts();`

As for pagination, there are [many plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=pagination) available, this one for example : [WP-Paginate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/)